# How do I create a plot from nlin using SAS 9.3?

Tags: plot, sas, regression

I have some data which I would like to model in SAS using a nonlinear model.

How can I produce an output plot, which shows my regression line?

Thanks

```
data ch13;
input Y X1 X2;
    Y_log = log10(Y);
    X1_log = log10(X1);
    X2_log = log10(X2);
datalines;
12  1   1
32  10  1
103 100 1
20  1   10
61  10  10
198 100 10
38  1   100
133 10  100
406 100 100
8   1   1
38  10  1
98  100 1
14  1   10
56  10  10
205 100 10
43  1   100
128 10  100
398 100 100
;
proc nlin data = ch13;
    parms   gamma0 = 9.59114
            gamma1 = 0.51485
            gamma2 = 0.29845;
    model Y = gamma0*(X1**gamma1)*(X2**gamma2);
run;
```

Comment: +1 for providing sample data and a clearly asked question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (stolen from [the SAS/STAT documentation here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_nlin_sect039.htm)):

```
ods graphics on;
proc nlin data = ch13 plots(stats=all)=(diagnostics);
    parms   gamma0 = 9.59114
            gamma1 = 0.51485
            gamma2 = 0.29845;
    model Y = gamma0*(X1**gamma1)*(X2**gamma2);
run;
ods graphics off;
```

I don't use NLIN myself, but the SAS documentation has many examples for things like this.

Comment: Thanks though, it was worth a shot, I am really new to the language so I struggle debugging such simple errors

Comment: Update your question with the complete log containing the error message.  I tested exactly what I posted using your sample data, so you probably have some stray syntax error.  I'm sure it's something simple.